# When to use nested class?

Tags: java, nested-class

The code below will find intersection of 2 lines and return the point object. If point is only ever going to be created by IntersectionOf2Lines class, should i make point a nested class ? If not then why not ? Thanks

```
class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

public class IntersectionOf2Lines {

    public static Point calculateIntersection(Line line1, Line line2) {
        int x = (line2.getConstant() - line1.getConstant()) / (line1.getSlope() - line2.getSlope());
        int y = line1.getSlope() * x + line1.getConstant();

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Main reason to crate nested classes is that they have access to all members of its parent class, also private ones. Does your Point instance will need that kind of access to IntersectionOf2Lines class members?

Comment: No. they dont need any access to IntersectionOf2Lines

Comment: I personally question whether you need the `calculateIntersection` method in a separate class to Point

Comment: Another question: are you planning to use Point class in other classes? If yes then it is also good reason to not make them nested, unless you want to use them with `IntersectionOf2Lines.Point` type reference.

Comment: yes, other class wil simply print result using getters. In general - if a function needs to return 2 values should it use an outer class or inner class ( like itr for example )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Point class is not needed by any other class and the Point class don't need access to the private class members of IntersectionOf2Lines, then you could make the Point class a *static nested class*.

A *static nested class* is a lighter inner class that has no access to the super class members and is often used like structs in C.

```
package main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyPoint p = new MyPoint();
        p.x = 5;
        System.out.println("x: "+ p.x);

    }

    private static class MyPoint {
        int x;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Point` is only created by `IntersectionOf2Lines`, I would implement it as a *static nested class*: This way you can declare the constructor to be `private`:

```
public class IntersectionOf2Lines {
    static class Point {
        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        private Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        int getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public static Point calculateIntersection(int line1, int line2) {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

If the constructor is `private`, the compiler enforces your design/intention.

This is especially useful, if the visibility of the class which contains the result is `public` (in your example, it's `package private`), and you do not want that other people instantiate "your" class, because this creates an additional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, Line is made of number of points. If you are creating Point class outside, you can use it to show point on particular line, end points of line, so it should be a normal class and not nested class to IntersectionOf2Lines.