# When to use nested class

Tags: java, design-patterns, nested-class

If a function returns 2 values, for example: min/max in array or for example, x and y axis of a point, it would need to create an object, since a function cannot return 2 values.

Now, consider a client whose 'only' function is to use getters in the returned object and print.
AND
The returned object say MinMax or Point object is created only by one class,

Should we use a nested class (eg: MinMax, Point can be nested class) or use a top level class?

This is a generic question - below is just one such example related to the question. Please done answer related to the code sample as it is a very generic question not bound to the sample code.

Should the Point class be inner class returned similar to the way itr is returned by arraylist ?

```
class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

public class IntersectionOf2Lines {

    public static Point calculateIntersection(Line line1, Line line2) {
        int x = (line2.getConstant() - line1.getConstant()) / (line1.getSlope() - line2.getSlope());
        int y = line1.getSlope() * x + line1.getConstant();

        return new Point(x, y);
    }


 Line line3 = new Line(2, 2);
         Line line4 = new Line(3, 2);

         Point p1 = IntersectionOf2Lines.calculateIntersection(line3, line4);
         System.out.println("Expected: x = 0, Actual x = " + p1.getX() + " Expected y=2, Actual y = " + p1.getY());
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17128389/edit) [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128389/when-to-use-nested-class) with that informations instead creating new one.

Comment: Note that if you need tp return several items of a kind, you can return a list or an array.

Comment: Sorry, very new to stack overflow. thanks for pointing out

Comment: The problem is that the usual answer to a generic question is that it will depend on the specific context.

Comment: selig - what would be your answer wrt the specific sample anyways ?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is a matter of style.  I would look at it from the point of view of someone who is reading your code from the first time.  Which classes do you want to make obvious and which ones do you want to group away and they only need to read when they get into the details.

BTW: A nested class need to be nested inside the scope of another class, not just in the same class file as it is in your example.

Comment: Point is not a nested class.. my question is 'should' Point be a nested class which can be returned just like Iterator is returned by Util classes ?

Comment: It should be if you believe that is a more "natural" way to write/read the code, and it wouldn't exist except for the outer class needing it. If you feel the class stands on its own, make it it's own class file.